# How to navigate to the same URL adding and parameter using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In my React application, a Route in the nav menu points to /persons url. When clicked, the rendered page shows all the available persons, let's say in a table. The user can then select a particular person to see the detail at the url /persons/:personId. However, when there is only one user available, the requirement is to directly show the person detail, and bypass the step to show table of persons.

In the React Component, I am trying to identify if there is only one person available in the  useEffect() and using react-router-dom's navigate(useLocation().pathname + "/" + personId).

Here is the relevant code snippets.

```
...
<Route path="/persons/:personId?" element={<Persons />} />
...
```

```
const { personId } = useParams();
const persons = // via some service call;
useEffect(() => {
    if (!personId && persons.length === 1) {
      useNavigate()(useLocation().pathname + "/" + persons[0].id);
    }
}, []);
...
```

With this I receive => 'Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.'

Here are my questions

- How to navigate to the same page having added a parameter from within the page?
- What is the best practice around this use-case? Should I render another component for /persons/:personId?

Comment: You cant use a hook inside an effect `useNavigate` and `useLocation`. Right now you redirect on every page load. You need logic to check if the `claimId` already is part of the url

Comment: You should have 2 components, one for the list and another for a single user. Then the single user component can determin what to show

Comment: Getting personId from useParams in line 1 and using the same in the if condition in line 4 is exactly there for what you are suggesting.

Comment: Also, if I take out useNavigate()(navurl) out of useEffect, react throws following 
'You should call navigate() in a React.useEffect(), not when your component is first rendered.'
suggesting I must use the opposite of what you (Vincent) are suggesting.

Comment: There's not really enough details to provide a sufficient solution. Please [edit] to include better details and a more complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice around this use-case? Should I render another component for /persons/:personId?

How about defining 2 Routes:

```
<Route path="/persons" element={<PersonList />} />
<Route path="/persons/:personId" element={<PersonDetails />} />
```

In `<PersonList />` you choose one of these actions:

1. If there are more then 1 users, show them all in a list
2. If there's just one, [navigate to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) the `<PersonDetails />` page

   ```
   if (persons.length === 1) {
       useNavigate()(useLocation().pathname + "/" + persons[0].id);
   }

   // Otherwise, `map()` each user
   ```

---

In `<PersonDetails />` you show the info based on `:personId`

Comment: This definitely is one option, I know, but is this a best practice? Usually, both these paths are better ratified in one Route.

Comment: Why? I've learned to use React Router as a single purpose page. Listing users isn't the same as showing user details and should be seperate components.